# Django Postgres app works perfectly on localhost but fails to load on Heroku after deployment from GitHub (error code H10, status 503)

Tags: django, postgresql, github, heroku

I have a Django app using PostgreSQL that works perfectly on localhost, but fails when deployed to Heroku.  I deploy via GitHub.  Although I can successfully deploy the Django app, I cannot access any url.  I have received various errors along the way.  The current one is HTTP status 503, although I was getting 500 for quite a while.  I have tried resetting my Heroku PostgreSQL database, deleting and recreating my database, running `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` post-deployment, performing migrations manually post-deployment (also using `release: python manage.py migrate --noinput` in my Procfile), `heroku reset`, and resetting my migrations and redeploying, but to no avail.

At one point, I had half of the admin working (this was before I finally figured out that my custom models weren't being migrated on heroku because I didn't include the migration files in the deployment.)  Now that I finally have the Django apps installed on heroku, I can't even load the admin, much less anything else:

> 2021-08-26T07:21:03.486150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/admin/" host=XXXXXXX.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx fwd="171.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503
> bytes= protocol=http

The webpage displays the following error message:

> Application error:
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

There are many questions/answers related to the various error messages I have encountered during this past week, but can't seem to resolve my issue.  Any more ideas?  Should I try deleting my heroku app and starting over?

Comment: You need to provide more log information. From the moment you run your app process to the moment you first access your application via the website. All those resulting logs are relevant

Comment: @TinNguyen, you are a genius!  And I am a Heroku noob.  Your comment actually helped me find my problem.  I had been looking at my logs, but I always looked at it after accessing a webpage, and so never saw the earlier logs that identified the issue.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is... look at your logs **before** you try to load a webpage.  This is what I finally saw when doing so:

```
2021-08-26T10:19:21.089432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-26T10:19:31.782829+00:00 app[web.1]: usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
2021-08-26T10:19:31.782950+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: —-log-file -
2021-08-26T10:19:31.838962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2021-08-26T10:19:31.931500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

If you look carefully, there are actually two different types of dashes that call the option `log-file` for the `gunicorn` command in my Procfile.  That was the issue!  Lesson learned: don't copy and paste code from the web so freely!